# How to update ref cursor values in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, ref-cursor

I want to fetch limited no. of rows using `refcursor`. then I need to update same set of records. is it possible?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE myproc (
        P_ROWCOUNT    IN    NUMBER,
        OUT_TXN_IDS   OUT   OF_CR_TYPE,
        P_CD_ERROR    OUT   NUMBER,
        P_DS_ERROR    OUT   VARCHAR2
    )
    AS
        V_TXNID NUMBER;

    BEGIN
        P_CD_ERROR := 0;
        P_DS_ERROR  := 'SUCCESS';

        OPEN OUT_TXN_IDS for
            SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE status='N' AND ROWNUM<=P_ROWCOUNT;
        
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            P_CD_ERROR :=  sqlcode;
            P_DS_ERROR := 'WF-ERROR - myproc - ' || substr(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
            RETURN;
END myproc;
```

I need to update same records to status Y after `refcursor` returns. can we do this. please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your tables nor data so I simplified it a little bit, but - it should work nonetheless.

Initial statuses:

```
SQL> SELECT status, count(*) FROM table1 group by status;

S   COUNT(*)
- ----------
Y          7
N          7
```

Procedure: basically, you'd modify rows represented by `ID` returned by ref cursor.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     out_txn_ids  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  3     p_rowcount   NUMBER := 5;
  4     l_id         table1.id%TYPE;
  5  BEGIN
  6     OPEN out_txn_ids FOR SELECT id
  7                            FROM table1
  8                           WHERE     status = 'N'
  9                                 AND ROWNUM <= p_rowcount;
 10
 11     LOOP
 12        FETCH out_txn_ids INTO l_id;
 13
 14        EXIT WHEN out_txn_ids%NOTFOUND;
 15
 16        UPDATE table1
 17           SET status = 'Y'
 18         WHERE id = l_id;
 19     END LOOP;
 20
 21     CLOSE out_txn_ids;
 22  END;
 23  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT status, count(*) FROM table1 group by status;

S   COUNT(*)
- ----------
Y         12
N          2

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. i have tried this and getting error `ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence`

Comment: You're welcome. If you got an error, you did something *wrong*. I wouldn't know what as I don't have your table(s) nor code you wrote.

Comment: also there are 15 rows in my table and I am passing 10 in row count but still all 15 rows get updated

Comment: yes issue was with my code as i forgot to close the cursor. Its working now thanks a lot